# How get NumberExpression<Integer> result using Spring JPA Data?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, querydsl

I used Spring JPA Data + queryDSL.

It's great solution. but I have one question now.

if I want to execute this query.

```
select sum(point) from users where userLevel = 2;
```

I have know how execute using queryDSL fro this query. But I don't know how execute this query using queryDSL and QueryDslPredicateExecutor.

How I execute this query using QueryDslPredicateExecutor? Is it imposible now? Either, there is another way to execute this query using Spring JPA another interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a Querydsl queries for that in Spring Data. `QueryDslPredicateExecutor` is the right choice if you want to return instances of the main variable type.

[QueryDslRepositorySupport](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.3.0.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/data/jpa/repository/support/QueryDslRepositorySupport.html) can be used as the superclass if you need full Querydsl power in a Spring Data repository.